# A model of self-organizing behavior

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I'd just like to know if the following model has received any attention:

A state at discrete time $t$ consists of a function $S_t:{\Bbb Z}^2\rightarrow S^1$.

So view each cell $c$ (element of ${\Bbb Z}^2$) as having eight neighbors in the usual way.

The update rule: set $S_{t+1}(c)$ equal that value $S_{t}(c')$,
for $c'$ a neighbor of $c$, occurring nearest to (but not coincident with) $S_t(c)$ when moving clockwise around $S^1$.

Computer simulation suggests that an random initial state quickly evolves to a pattern
reminiscent of lichens provided one represents locations on $S^1$ with shades of gray
(despite the unfortunate spurious discontinuity).  In time some of the "lichens" (distinguished visually one from another by their prevailing shade) grow while others eventually get absorbed.

Comment: I have no idea if that has been done before, but you could use hue instead of gray-scale to avoid the discontinuity.

Comment: @Ricky  Right, have done, but actually the psychological effect is similar as the map from hues to qualia seems to break the symmetry.

Comment: Reminds me of the voter models studied in cellular automata: each person does a local poll of his $k$-neighbourhood and adjusts his vote accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if this has been looked at before either, but it seems to me that it's won't lead to particularly interesting dynamics.  Once two neighboring cells have the same shade, they will never change again.  Anything adjacent to such a cell can only move counterclockwise as far as the frozen shade and as long as you have only finitely many different shades to begin with, after finitely many steps, that cell will freeze as well.  So either everything eventually freezes, or nothing freezes ever.

Comment: On second thought, if you pin down the cases where nothing freezes ever (rare though I expect those cases to be), that would be interesting.

Comment: Thanks Aubrey...if nothing else, you remarks made me realize that I wasn't clear (my edit fixes this).  The rule in my simulation will only leave a cell unchanged if all the neighbors has the same value that occurs at the hub.

Comment: This seems related to the literature on "pulse-coupled oscillators," which is inspired partly by models of synchronized firefly flashing or cricket chirping. It may not treat your exact rule, but if you haven't looked into this already, see for instance: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~degesys/pulse.html